# On density of function spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Does there exist nonconstant function $h$ $\in$ $L^{2}([0,1]\times [0,1], \mu(\text{ lebesgue }))$ $E=\{(x,y)\mapsto f(x)f(y)h(x,y):f \in C[0,1]\}$ is  dense in $L^{2}([0,1]\times [0,1], \mu(\text{ lebesgue }))$? I am looking for elaboarated answer thanks in advance!!

Comment: certainly not: how would you get the characteristic function of the set $[0,1/2]\times[0,1/2]$ or of the set $\{0\le x\le y\le1\}$ in the closure

Comment: pLEASE GIVE DETAILED PROOF

Comment: If one has to check density removing constant functions and characteristic function in that case is the same idea will go through!!

Comment: Hint: How would you prove that $\{(x,y)\mapsto f(x)f(y)\}$ is not dense?